# How to add a tab every time I click on New Item

Tags: java

Hi everyone so I want to create a tab each time i click on New item :

```
     barreMenus = new JMenuBar() ;
        setJMenuBar(barreMenus) ;

        fichier = new JMenu ("Fichier") ;
        barreMenus.add(fichier) ;

        new = new JMenuItem ("nouveau") ;
        nouveau.addActionListener(this);
        fichier.add (new) ;

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
  { 
       if (e.getSource()==new)

    {   
        JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
        JPanel panel01 = new JPanel();
        tp.addTab("Panel 1", panel01); 
        this.add(tp);}}
```

but that doesn't work, what should i do ??
THANK YOU !

Comment: @JanKaufmann 
It works but when I click the first time on "new" that does not work but when I click the second time two tab appears

Comment: Get this `this.add(tp)` also out of the *actionPerformed*. Basically you'll keep re-adding *tab* not the container (*JTabbedPane*).

Comment: @JanKaufmann thank you !!!!